# Clojure to Java Interop

Tags: clojure

I am trying to get javafx2 working with Clojure - In implementing an abstract class such as DoubleBinding, I am unsure what the equivalent of super.bind(moo) is in Clojure. The class I am implementing can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html.

```
(def moo (ObservableDoubleValue. ...))
(def foo (proxy [DoubleBinding] []
            (computeValue []
               (Math/sqrt (.getValue moo)))))



final ObservableDoubleValue moo = ...;   
DoubleBinding foo = new DoubleBinding() {
     {
         super.bind(moo);
     }

     @Override
     protected double computeValue() {
         return Math.sqrt(moo.getValue());
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [proxy documentation](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/proxy), methods in proxy has no access to `super`...  I would recommend you to generate class using [`gen-class`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class) and use it. You can access to `super`'s methods if you'll expose them with `:exposes-methods` directive. Something, like:

```
(gen-class :name MyDoubleBinding
           :extends DoubleBinding
           :exposes-methods {bind my-bind}
 ....
 )
```

and then call `-my-bind` from your constructor...

Please, check [documentation about class](http://clojure.org/compilation) generation on Clojure's site for more details on `gen-class`

Comment: What about [`proxy-super`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/proxy-super)?

Comment: I have attempted to use proxy-super, however from what I have tested and read, it must be called from inside a method of the proxy. I have been testing gen-class and am unable to call .bindSuper in the post-init constructor, but still I try - it is very slow going since gen-class needs recompilation with each change.